# Why doesn't clojure.test/run-all-tests find tests when run from a leiningen plugin?

Tags: unit-testing, plugins, clojure, leiningen

I have a leiningen plugin consisting of the following function:

```
(defn vscode-test
  "Simple test run"
  [project & args]
  (leiningen.core.eval/eval-in-project project `(clojure.test/run-all-tests)))
```

When I run this with `lein vscode-test` inside a Clojure project with a `project.clj` file `clojure.test/run-all-tests` runs, but it doesn't find any of the tests in the project. Note that `lein test` does run all the tests.

My `project.clj` is

```
(defproject repl_test "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :source-paths ["src" "test" "dev"]
  :plugins [[vscode-test "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"]]
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                 [org.clojure/core.async "0.3.442"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.namespace "0.2.11"]])
```

Why doesn't the plugin see the tests?

Comment: I think it would help if you included your `project.clj` contents in the question.

Comment: Added project.clj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clojure.test/run-all-tests` runs all currently defined tests. `lein test` first loads the test definitions in the `test` directory and then calls the `clojure.test` code.

In other words; you're not running any tests because the code you've provided doesn't load / require the namespaces containing your tests.

Comment: That makes sense. I assumed `run-all-tests` would load them, but it makes sense that it only runs them if they are already loaded.